# Add multiple elements to shapeless HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

How to add multiple items to `HList`?

My naive version doesn't compile:

```
(1 to 100).foldLeft(HNil)((l,i) => i :: l)
```

For ordinary `List`s this approach would work well. For `HList`, however, I assume, it's required to provide a `Poly2` that takes a single item and a HList and returns the appended list.

Of course, if there are any better ways to add multiple item, those approaches would be very appreciated.

Comment: What would be the type of the result ?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet A HList with only Ints, so I guess it would be Int::...::Int::HNil (sure, in this simple example I could use an ordinary list, but my real use case is more complex and I'm already failing at this initial step.)

Comment: How can `foldLeft` return a type that depends on the length of the list on which it is applied? Your problem is that you want to transform dynamic information (the length of your range) into static information (the length of the `HList`, which is encoded in its type). You won't be able to do it.

Comment: Maybe you should try going for a [sized](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/sized.scala) collection. You can simply convert them to an `HList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But what you are trying to do here could be done with a Sized collection.

```
scala> import shapeless._, syntax.sized._
import shapeless._
import syntax.sized._

scala> (1 to 10).reverse.toList.ensureSized[nat._10].toHList
res1: shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]]]]]]]]]] = 10 :: 9 :: 8 :: 7 :: 6 :: 5 :: 4 :: 3 :: 2 :: 1 :: HNil
```

If you want a range of 100 you have the problem that `nat._100` doesn't exist, so you have to create that yourself. I would just calculate it:

```
val prod = the[ops.nat.Prod[nat._10, nat._10]]
type _100 = prod.Out
(1 to 100).reverse.toList.ensureSized[_100].toHList
```

Comment: Yes, your right, it's a XY problem, thanks for the hint. What I simply want to achieve is to add a few thousands elements to conduct some simple benchmarks (as I want to use the HList a simple heterogeneous map without any need for implicits etc, this, however, has the drawback of O(n) read access, hence I want benchmark it).